# DocuSign Service integration authentication with jwt

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, docusignapi

I want to implement DocuSign Service integration authentication with jwt flow.

I’ve generated valid jwt (validated on jwt.io) and I can successfully obtain access token based on jwt according to https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html#requesting-the-access-token

I found on this blog post: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-docusign-developers-look-inside-new-authentication-apis/  that sub claim should be omitted  in case application represents user in the system (which I need):

> sub:  The user id of the principal you are requesting a token for. If omitted a token will be issued to represent the application itself instead of a user in the system. Required: No

But in next step "Obtaining the Base URI" that states:

> The first thing you should do after getting your access token is to use the /oauth/userinfo endpoint to get user’s account and base URI information that you’ll use to access the DocuSign API.
>
> GET /oauth/userinfo Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eX...AnHDQ0bbA

Fails with status code 401 Unauthorized with response body details:

```
{
    "error": "internal_server_error",
    "reference_id": "e051ca48-....f0f"
}
```

I also tried to call Login (from AuthenticationApi - DocuSign.NetCore 1.1.0 nuget package), with default authorization header containing an access token like this:

```
        Configuration.Default.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken));
        AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi(Configuration.Default);            
        LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();
```

Code above works only if I use OAuth2 access token that I can obtain directly from api explorer:
https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Authentication&tags=Authentication&operations=login&mode=basic
but when I use access token that I've obtained by following official documentation (described above) I get exception:

> DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: ‘Error calling Login: {
>       “errorCode”: “USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED”,
>       “message”: “One or both of Username and Password are invalid. Invalid access token”.

What seems to be that I'm missing?

Comment: Please upvote all useful answers. Please "check" (accept) the most helpful answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Amit says, you need to provide a userID (guid format). The fact that you're receiving the `Consent Required` is good news: you're almost there.

Your user can grant consent individually or you can grant blanket consent at the org level if you have org admin turned on.

See my [video](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-developing-docusign-application-authentication/) or [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-using-the-oauth-jwt-flow/) for how to individually grant consent.

Comment: Thank you, I've granted consent on organization level and solved initial issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ommitting `sub` is not yet implemented, it is a future state which is yet to be implemented. As of now, you always need to pass `sub` in the call, and you can get Accesstoken for a user only. That's a blog link with the big picture overview of what's coming with new OAUTH, but whats currently implemented is available at [DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html)

Comment: Thanks @Amit K Bist, but after adding `sub` I get `405 Bad request` with  `"error": "consent_required"` and I do not want to use consents. I would like anonymous users to be able sign an agreement before registering in the application. In fact, signing an agreement is obligatory in order to register in the app. I've read about user and admin consent on docs but it seems that none of them fits in this scenario. What would you recommend in this scenario?

Comment: Can you please explain the usecase which you are solving, because OAUTH is for sender's authentication and OAUTH is not needed for Signers. Why you are generating JWT tokens for Signers?

Comment: I am trying to implement is Embedded signing. Signer is anonymous user from the perspective of my app at the time of signing. Signer also shouldn't be authenticated against docusign. My app needs to create and send envelopes and generate recipient signing URL. In order to do so, my app needs to obtain access token from docusign. Access token that I can obtain using docs and that should represent my application according to Service Integration Authentication flow is invalid when I send it in Authorization header when using EnvelopeApi or AuthenticationApi as discribed in my main question.

Comment: Embedded Signing does not require creating Access Token. As I mentioned in my earlier comment AccessToken is required for sender's authentication, not signers. For embedded signing, DocuSign expects that your App will authenticate signer in some way, like username/password etc, once your App has authenticated user to know who the signer is then you will call DS [EnvelopeViews: createRecipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) to create signing uri. Also check, [example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/embedding)

Comment: For getting accesstoken for your sender, how you are getting Consent of the user (for whom you wan to get access token), you are using User Consent or Admin Consent, by above error in your first comment it seems you do not have consent from the user to generate Access Token on that user's behalf. Please check a nice Video Blog by Larry explaining the User Consent flow, [Service Integration](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-developing-docusign-application-authentication/), this page also has some useful links for your reference to understand flow of getting user consent.